# Error remote access MongoDB on Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, remote-access

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 Linux server with MongoDB 3.2.4 running at Digital Ocean as a droplet (one-click Apps).

Pinging the server works (droplet is distroyed after posting this):

```
ping 198.199.125.101
```

I created database `test` and user:

```
db.createUser({"user": "test", "pwd": "test", "roles": ["dbOwner"]})
```

In `mongod.conf` I changed `bindIp: 0.0.0.0` and restarted mongoDB

I disabled the firewall and reboot the server. Just for test, just to prove iptables is not the issue (don't do this on a regular server):

```
sudo ufw disable
```

The problem is I can't get remote access to the mongo Database

```
mongo 198.199.125.101:27021/test -u "test" -p "test"
```

Error message (connection refused):

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0
connecting to: 198.199.125.101:27021/test
2016-05-11T22:05:35.876+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 198.199.125.101:27021, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2016-05-11T22:05:35.879+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 198.199.125.101:27021, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:226:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Comment: bindIp: 198.199.125.101 also the same?

Comment: also mongodb port is 27017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run `netstat` on the mongo machine to verify that the port 27021 is open. `netstat -anp` should do it.

Then do "telnet 127.0.0.1 27021" to make sure it is open.

Once you are sure the port is open, then use `telnet 198.199.125.101 27021` to verify you can connect to the mongo machine on port 27021. If you can, then it has something to do with your app. If not then something is blocking the connection. Some firewall or something. Are you on aws?

As per netstat, can you try `mongo 198.199.125.101:27017/test -u "test" -p "test"`

Comment: Netstat -anp gives....... Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      878/mongod   
That look good doesn't it?

Comment: telnet 127.0.0.1 27021..... gives an error......Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: Wait a moment. 27017 or 27021?

Comment: Try mongo 198.199.125.101:27017/test -u "test" -p "test". instead of 27021

Comment: This solves the problem. I feel so stupid!! Thank your very much and sorry wasting your time. I wasted a day searching this problem. grrrr... but I learned a lot too.......